# How to select columns from dataframe by regex

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe in python pandas. The structure of the dataframe is as the following:

```
   a    b    c    d1   d2   d3 
   10   14   12   44  45    78
```

I would like to select the columns which begin with d. Is there a simple way to achieve this in python .

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) this way:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2,4,4],[4,3,3],[5,9,1]]),columns=['d','t','didi'])
>>
   d  t  didi
0  2  4     4
1  4  3     3
2  5  9     1

df.filter(regex=("d.*"))

>>
   d  didi
0  2     4
1  4     3
2  5     1
```

The idea is to select columns by `regex`

Comment: To get a filtered list of just column names `df.filter(regex=("d.*")).columns.to_list()`.

Comment: This seems to be very incorrect - if you replace the column name 't' with 'td', then the regex picks up all three columns. It's as if the regex doesn't start at the beginning of the column name. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @FarazMasroor search for `^d.*`; ^ looks for proceeding regex that starts the string. But I think a more accurate regex in this case -- assuming numbers follow "d" -- is `^d\d+` where `\d` means digit and `+` is for 1 or more of preceding character

Answer (score 27):

### Update

Use `.str.startswith` on `df.columns`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 14, 12, 44, 45, 78]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3'])

df[df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('d')]]
```

Result:

```
   d1  d2  d3
0  44  45  78
```

This is a nice solution if you're not comfortable with regular expressions.

### Old answer, for pandas pre-v0.21.0

Use `select`:

```
df.select(lambda col: col.startswith('d'), axis=1)
```

Note: `select` was deprecated as of pandas v0.21.0 - thanks to [Venkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5725669/venkat-ramana) for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: Beware that select is now getting deprecated

Answer (score 15):

On a larger dataset especially, a vectorized approach is actually MUCH FASTER (**by more than two orders of magnitude**) and is MUCH more readable.
I'm providing a screenshot as proof. 
(Note: Except for the last few lines I wrote at the bottom to make my point clear with a **vectorized approach**, the other code was derived from the answer by @Alexander.)

[image]

Here's that code for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n = 10000
cols = ['{0}_{1}'.format(letters, number) 
        for number in range(n) for letters in ('d', 't', 'didi')]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30000, n * 3), columns=cols)

%timeit df[[c for c in df if c[0] == 'd']]

%timeit df[[c for c in df if c.startswith('d')]]

%timeit df.select(lambda col: col.startswith('d'), axis=1)

%timeit df.filter(regex=("d.*"))

%timeit df.filter(like='d')

%timeit df.filter(like='d', axis=1)

%timeit df.filter(regex=("d.*"), axis=1)

%timeit df.columns.map(lambda x: x.startswith("d"))

columnVals = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.startswith("d"))

%timeit df.filter(columnVals, axis=1)
```

Comment: I couldn't get your approach to filter my dataframe, using the last 2 lines my result is empty... no columns... does this method still work?

Comment: @RachOdwyer I'd think it should work unless perhaps they rolled out a breaking change. If that's the case, please let me know.

Comment: a little bit late: you can use df.loc[:, columnVals] instead

Comment: This comparison is very misleading. It is so misleading, in fact, that this method is just plain wrong.  It is fast because `filter` is returning an empty dataframe.  `x.startswith("d")` results in `True` or `False`, neither of which are column names and hence why the returned dataframe is empty. The correct way to implement your idea is `columnVals = df.columns.map(lambda x: x if x.startswith("d") else None)`.  Then you will see after filtering that the time is the same as the other approaches.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over all of the column names in your DataFrame `df` and then only select those that begin with 'd'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 10}, 'b': {0: 14}, 'c': {0: 12},
                   'd1': {0: 44}, 'd2': {0: 45}, 'd3': {0: 78}})
```

Use list comprehension to iterate over the columns in the dataframe and return their names (`c` below is a local variable representing the column name).

```
>>> [c for c in df]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3']
```

Then only select those beginning with 'd'.

```
>>> [c for c in df if c[0] == 'd']  # As an alternative to c[0], use c.startswith(...)
['d1', 'd2', 'd3']
```

Finally, pass this list of columns to the DataFrame.

```
df[[c for c in df if c.startswith('d')]]
>>> df
   d1  d2  d3
0  44  45  78
```

===========================================================================

**TIMINGS** (added Feb 2018 per comments from devinbost claiming that this method is slow...)

First, lets create a dataframe with 30k columns:

```
n = 10000
cols = ['{0}_{1}'.format(letters, number) 
        for number in range(n) for letters in ('d', 't', 'didi')]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, n * 3), columns=cols)
>>> df.shape
(3, 30000)

>>> %timeit df[[c for c in df if c[0] == 'd']]  # Simple list comprehension.
# 10 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop

>>> %timeit df[[c for c in df if c.startswith('d')]]  # More 'pythonic'?
# 10 loops, best of 3: 29.2 ms per loop

>>> %timeit df.select(lambda col: col.startswith('d'), axis=1)  # Solution of gbrener.
# 10 loops, best of 3: 21.4 ms per loop

>>> %timeit df.filter(regex=("d.*"))  # Accepted solution.
# 10 loops, best of 3: 40 ms per loop
```

Comment: I don't get the code. what is the c in there. and did you test the code, please offer some explanations.

Comment: `c.startswith('d')` is probably more pythonic. Either way I like this!

Comment: This is extremely slow. A vectorized approach would be greatly preferred.

Comment: @devinbost Your request is a pathetic cheap shot and comes nearly two years after the OP's question.  The OP asked "Is there a simple way to achieve this in python", to which my reply would work in the majority of situations.  If you have a _specific_ requirement that calls on dataframes with a large number of columns or with many dataframes, then I suggest you ask a question more specific to your needs.

Comment: @Alexander The fact that you were offended by my comment doesn't change that it's bad advice to give people solutions that are generally discouraged by community best practices because people will feel misled. I think vector-based solutions are often simpler anyway.

Comment: I also reason that people using Pandas often do have large amounts of data. Vectorization and improved performance with large amounts of data are among the main benefits of using a library like Pandas. In my case, vectorization improved compute time from over 4 hours to about 87 seconds, and I was computing twice as much in the refactored version.

Comment: @devinbost I really don't think you understand the meaning of 'vectorization`.  Please see my added timings that demonstrate my initial answer is 2.5x faster than the accepted solution.  If you have a _new_ question with specific requirements, please ask it.

Comment: @Alexander that's because the filter operation uses a regex...You're comparing apples to oranges. Consider the advice from here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html or here: 
https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Comment: @devinbost You are free to post your own solution.  It is poor etiquette to complain years after the fact for a question that was not asked. You are barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: @devinbost, the links you posted refer to optimization _row-wise_, and this post explicitly asked about selection _column-wise_, so your ranting about community best practices are really out of place. For common data analysis, columns will rarely be more than a hundred, and there is no need for vectorization.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the method `startswith` with index (columns in this case):

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('d')]
```

or `match` with regex:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.match('^d')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
df.filter(regex='^d')
```

Comment: If I want to filter columns endswith `d`?

Answer (score 0):

Get any substring of column names starting with a [abc] until '_', drop any non-matches (NA), remove duplicates and sort.

```
df.columns.str.extract(r'([abc].*_)', expand=False).dropna().drop_duplicates().sort_values()
```