# Pandas select columns with regex and divide by value

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to divide all values in certain columns matching a regex expression by some value and still have the complete dataframe.

As can be found here: [How to select columns from dataframe by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808430/how-to-select-columns-from-dataframe-by-regex) , e.g. all columns starting with d can be selected with:

```
df.filter(regex=("d.*"))
```

Now I have the columns selected I need, I want e.g. divide the values by 2. Which is possible with the following code:

```
df.filter(regex=("d.*")).divide(2)
```

However if I try to update my dataframe like this, it gives a `can't assign to function call`:

```
df.filter(regex=("d.*")) = df.filter(regex=("d.*")).divide(2)
```

How to properly update my existing df?

Comment: There is an actual method named update that was designed for this exact purpose.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48259109/2336654.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following technique is not limited to use with filter and can be applied far more generally.

**Setup**
I'll use @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ setup
Let `df` be:

```
   d1  d2  abc
0   5   1    8
1  13   8    6
2   9   4    7
3   9  16   15
4   1  20    9
```

---

**Inplace update**
Use [**`pd.DataFrame.update`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)
`update` will take the argument dataframe and alter the calling dataframe where index and column values match the argument.

```
df.update(df.filter(regex='d.*') / 3)
df

         d1        d2  abc
0  1.666667  0.333333    8
1  4.333333  2.666667    6
2  3.000000  1.333333    7
3  3.000000  5.333333   15
4  0.333333  6.666667    9
```

---

**Inline copy**
Use [**`pd.DataFrame.assign`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
I use the double splat `**` to unpack the argument dataframe into a dictionary where column names are keys and the series that are the columns are the values.  This matches the required signature for `assign` and overwrites those columns in the copy that is produced.  In short, this is a copy of the calling dataframe with the columns overwritten appropriately.

```
df.assign(**df.filter(regex='d.*').div(3))

         d1        d2  abc
0  1.666667  0.333333    8
1  4.333333  2.666667    6
2  3.000000  1.333333    7
3  3.000000  5.333333   15
4  0.333333  6.666667    9
```

Comment: Nice to an answer from you every now and then. :)

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ!

Comment: They were all good answers, but since this one is the most general, and short in code, I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 10):

I think you need extract columns names and assign:

```
df[df.filter(regex=("d.*")).columns] = df.filter(regex=("d.*")).divide(2)
```

Or:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('^d.*')]
df[cols] /=2
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `df.columns.str.startswith`.

```
c = df.columns.str.startswith('d')    
df.loc[:, c] /= 2
```

As an example, consider -

```
df

   d1  d2  abc
0   5   1    8
1  13   8    6
2   9   4    7
3   9  16   15
4   1  20    9

c = df.columns.str.startswith('d')  
c
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

df.loc[:, c] /= 3    # 3 instead of 2, just for example
df

         d1        d2  abc
0  1.666667  0.333333    8
1  4.333333  2.666667    6
2  3.000000  1.333333    7
3  3.000000  5.333333   15
4  0.333333  6.666667    9
```

---

If you need to pass a regex, use `str.contains` -

```
c = df.columns.str.contains(p) # p => your pattern
```

And the rest of your code follows.

Comment: Thanks as well. Your answer solves the example question, but I used that, because it is simplified. My own code needs a more complex regex, so startswith doesn't cut the case for that.

Comment: @NumesSanguis Then use `df.columns.str.contains`, and pass a regex. Still simpler.

Comment: `df.loc[:, c] /= 2` is lovely, never thought of that one!

Comment: @RobinNemeth Yup, you would've seen it in my answer first ;)