# Pandas how can 'replace' work after 'loc'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried many times, but seems the 'replace' can NOT work well after use 'loc'.
For example I want to replace the 'conlumn_b' with an regex for the row that the 'conlumn_a' value is 'apple'.

Here is my sample code :

```
df.loc[df['conlumn_a'] == 'apple', 'conlumn_b'].replace(r'^11*', 'XXX',inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Example:

```
conlumn_a       conlumn_b
apple           123
banana          11
apple           11
orange          33
```

The result that I expected for the 'df' is:

```
conlumn_a       conlumn_b
apple           123
banana          11
apple           XXX
orange          33
```

Anyone has meet this issue that needs 'replace' with regex after 'loc' ?

OR you guys has some other good solutions ?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: This question could be improved by providing code to produce the df. That code should make the numbers str rather than int types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need filter in both sides:

```
m = df['conlumn_a'] == 'apple'
df.loc[m,'conlumn_b'] = df.loc[m,'conlumn_b'].astype(str).replace(r'^(11+)','XXX',regex=True)
print (df)
  conlumn_a conlumn_b
0     apple       123
1    banana        11
2     apple       XXX
3    orange        33
```

Comment: But I got the same concern as you about the 'update' : it's faster or not. I think I am going to have a test about it.

Comment: @JonathanZhou - The best test it, but in my opinion it is slowier.

Comment: @jezrael do you know why the `df[df[col1=='aa']][col2] = df[df[col1=='aa']][col2].replace(map_dict)` won't work?

Comment: @mingchau - problem is chained indexing, check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=settingwithcopywarning#evaluation-order-matters) - it is repalce only filtered Series, not DataFrame slice

Answer (score 14):

`inplace=True` works on the object that it was *applied on*.

When you call `.loc`, you're slicing your dataframe object to return a *new* one.

```
>>> id(df)
4587248608
```

And,

```
>>> id(df.loc[df['conlumn_a'] == 'apple', 'conlumn_b'])
4767716968
```

Now, calling an in-place `replace` on this new slice will apply the replace operation, updating the *new slice itself*, and not the original.

---

Now, note that you're calling `replace` on a column of *`int`*, and nothing is going to happen, because regular expressions work on strings.

Here's what I offer you as a workaround. Don't use regex at all.

```
m = df['conlumn_a'] == 'apple'
df.loc[m, 'conlumn_b'] = df.loc[m, 'conlumn_b'].replace(11, 'XXX')

df

  conlumn_a conlumn_b
0     apple       123
1    banana        11
2     apple       XXX
3    orange        33
```

Or, if you *need* regex based substitution, then -

```
df.loc[m, 'conlumn_b'] = df.loc[m, 'conlumn_b']\
           .astype(str).replace('^11$', 'XXX', regex=True)
```

Although, this converts your column to an object column.

Comment: Thanks and I will take you suggestion. The situation is that I need regex in the 'replace', the '11 to XXX' is only a sample and the actually regex can be more complex.@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Thank you for explaining the cause of the problem: I wasn't aware `loc` was creating a new object. Always good to understand the underlying cause.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Isn't `loc` supposed to provide an assignable view?  Why does replace work after `loc` when doing ordinary replacement, but not when doing regex replacement?

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to borrow from a [**recent answer of mine**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48259109/2336654).  This technique is a general purpose strategy for updating a dataframe in place:

```
df.update(
    df.loc[df['conlumn_a'] == 'apple', 'conlumn_b']
      .replace(r'^11$', 'XXX', regex=True)
)

df

  conlumn_a conlumn_b
0     apple       123
1    banana        11
2     apple       XXX
3    orange        33
```

Note that all I did was remove the `inplace=True` and instead wrapped it in the [**`pd.DataFrame.update`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) method.

Comment: @piRSquared - Why is `update` better? It is faster? Or nicer code only?

Comment: Nicer code.  Using it for its intended purpose.  I show how it should be used to accomplish what people meant to accomplish with `inplace=True` but couldn't because they were performing it on a subsequent object.

Comment: This is actually nicer code, but it's completely not performant vs the `.loc` alternative sadly. Just tried it on 2M rows, it doesn't run in less than one minute, and had to stop it. Meanwhile the "dirty" `.loc` alternative runs instantly