# Why the pandas replace won't work in a df slice?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
| action   | spans | product_id     | created_at      |
|----------|-------|----------------|-----------------|
| sign_in  | 0     | 2201           | 2019/3/10 12:11 |
| order    | 0     | 449            | 2019/4/13 14:58 |
```

And  a dict of `product = {'2201': 'project a'}`

I want to replace the `product_id` with the value of the dict product, where the action is sign_in.

But the code

```py
df[df['action']=='sign_in']]['product_id'].replace（product, inplace=True)
```

Does not work.

Could anyone help to explain? Thanks.

Comment: slice with replace inplace will not work , try using assign


`df.loc[df['action']=='sign_in','product_id']=df.loc[df['action']=='sign_in','product_id'].replace{product)`

Comment: This might be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48315104/7838574 look at the last answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why `inplace=True` does not work on a masked DF, but you can achieve the same (perhaps even better to read) by:

```
df.update(df.loc[df['action']=='sign_in','product_id'].replace(product))
```