# Pandas assignment vs inplace=True on .loc?

Tags: python, pandas, in-place

After reading the Pandas docs and some articles my understanding was that using .loc instead of chained indexing will give a view instead of a copy... so in the code below why does inplace=True fail and why does assignment with `=` work?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id': 'A', 'value': 200},
    {'id': 'B', 'value': 5},
    {'id': 'A', 'value': 200},
])

# This doesn't modify df
df.loc[df['id'] == 'A', 'value'].replace({200:300}, inplace=True)

# This doesn't modify df
df.loc[df['id'] == 'A', 'value'].drop(0, inplace=True)

# This does modify df
df.loc[df['id'] == 'A', 'value'] = 400
```

Comment: There seem to be some [strange rules](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) surrounding when views actually mutate their underlying df in all the red.

Comment: In particular, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48315104/3483203).  Pandas is able to handle the direct assignment here, but when you call `replace` with `inplace`, it is operating on a different object.

Comment: @user3483203 I read that before writing this question, I don't think it's a duplicate. The answers give alternative ways to modify a df but I just want to understand why inplace doesn't work. The only explanation in that thread is "When you call .loc, you're slicing your dataframe object to return a new one." which raises my question why does it work with `=` assignment

Comment: @user3483203 *[removed], I'm to stupid to python today*

Comment: @Esostack see [this pandas issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) and [subsequent discussions](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529#issuecomment-323890422). Simply put: don't use `inplace`.