# Why does DataFrame.clip inplace not work on a multi-column view?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have this toy `DataFrame`:

```
>>> data = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["a", "b", "c"])
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
```

First note that both `df.loc[:,"a"]` and `df.loc[:,["a", "b"]]` are views. If we assign to them, this is reflected in the original dataframe:

```
>>> df.loc[:,"a"] = 4
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  4  2  3
1  4  3  4
2  4  4  5

>>> df.loc[:,["a", "b"]] = 5
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  5  5  3
1  5  5  4
2  5  5  5
```

But `.clip` with `inplace=True` does not seem to work with a multi-column view:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["a", "b", "c"])
>>> df.loc[:,"a"].clip(lower=4, inplace=True)  # Works.
>>> df
a  b  c
0  4  2  3
1  4  3  4
2  4  4  5

>>> df.loc[:,["a", "b"]].clip(lower=5, inplace=True)  # Does not work.
>>> df  # First two columns should be all fives now.
a  b  c
0  4  2  3
1  4  3  4
2  4  4  5
```

What's going on here? I'm using `pandas` version 0.24.2.

Comment: IIUC, you cannot do a inplace operation on a slice of the dataframe using `.loc[]`, you have to resassign it back: `df.loc[:,["a", "b"]]=df.loc[:,["a", "b"]].clip(lower=5)` , OTOH, `df.loc[:,"a"].clip(lower=4, inplace=True) ` works because `df.loc[:,"a"]` returns a series

Comment: This is another example of confusing behaviour/expectation that using `.loc` solves whether we are working on a view or copy. I never use `inplace=True` and just assign back because of this subtle behaviour. You could argue whether it's a bug/defined/etc.. but I'd just assign back to avoid ambiguity

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314971/pandas-how-can-replace-work-after-loc/48315104#48315104 also related [git issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) . Hope that helps :)