# passing a dataframe as a argument while applying a lambda function on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I am applying a lambda function on a data frame and would like to add a new column to that dataframe, while applying the lambda function I am passing the data frame it self as a argument to the function.

dataset

```
      SL. No.  Class   Age  time  ...  demand  from_ind  to_ind      Fare
0           1      0  77.2    39  ...       1         5       4  11854.27
1           2      0  45.3    34  ...       1         2       4  14968.50
2           3      0  70.9    36  ...       1         1       4   5859.32
3           4      0  35.1    31  ...       1         7       4   2774.19
4           5      0  41.8    33  ...       1         7       4   3833.66
```

My code

```
def categorical_fare_mean(data,col,cat):
    print('entered once')
    data = data[data[col]==cat]['Fare']
    fare_mean = data['Fare'].mean()
    return fare_mean

dataset['weekday_encoded'] = dataset.apply(lambda x: categorical_fare_mean(dataset,x['weekday'],0) ,axis = 1)
```

This is giving me an error `KeyError: (0, 'occurred at index 0')` I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can some one help me with it.

I have also tried with

```
dataset['demand_encoded'] = dataset.apply(lambda x: categorical_fare_mean(dataset,x['demand'],1) ,axis = 1)
```

I got an error `KeyError: (1, 'occurred at index 0')`
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what `dataset` looks like?

Comment: `df.loc[df['weekday']==0]['Fare'].mean()` ? you don't need to use such an expensive operation for a simple thing that pandas can handle.

Comment: @Datanovice that is what my function `categorical_fare_mean` does, right ? I want to add a column with the calculated mean value for each row. So trying to achieve it by `df.apply`

Comment: then you can use `.loc` `df.loc[df['weekday']==0, 'demand_encoded'] = df['Fare'].mean()` - change df with dataset. it's unclear what you need, as no weekday in your dataset nor have you posted what you want your data to look like?

Comment: `df.loc[df['weekday']==0, 'demand_encoded'] = df['Fare'].mean()` has worked, thanks !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas how can 'replace' work after 'loc'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314971/pandas-how-can-replace-work-after-loc)

Comment: no problemo, I've voted to mark this as a duplicate this as there are quite a few answers that go into detail in regards to `.loc` assignment. best of luck.