# How can I locate a subgroup of a dataframe based on more than one variable and replace a value only for that subgroup in the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am quite new in Python and I have been facing some trouble to do the following:

I have a dataframe that I had to group based on different variables in order to analyze the data.

```
   Package Package category Moisture  Length  Height      Packing weight
0      YYS                X  NON DRY    2000     200             200
1      XXS                Y  NON DRY     190      20             200
2      GGT                Z      DRY     350      32             680
3      YYS                X      DRY    1000     209             280
4      YYS                X      DRY    3500     209             280
5      GGT                Z      DRY     350      37             680
6      XXS                Y  NON DRY     345      29             600
7      GGT                Z      DRY     350      37             680
8      GGT                Z      DRY     350      37             680
9      YYS                X      DRY    2000     209             285
10     YYS                X  NON DRY    3400     200             200
11     YYS                X      DRY    2000     209             280
12     XXS                Y  NON DRY     190      23             200
13     XXS                Y  NON DRY     190      23             200
14     GGT                Z  NON DRY     190      23             200
15     XXS                Y  NON DRY     190      23             200
16     GGT                Z  NON DRY     190      23             200
17     XXS                Y  NON DRY     336      20             600
18     XXS                Y  NON DRY     190      23             200
```

1. For this analysis, I search for a specific group, using the following:

```
data1.loc[(data1['Package category'] == 'X') & (data1['Package'] == 'YYS') & (data1['Moisture'] == 'DRY') 
          & (data1['Length'] == 2000) & (data1['Height'] == 209.0),:]
```

2. From that specific group I found that the values for the column 'Packing weight' are varying within this group and I would like to just have one values, therefore I need to replace all the rows if that group that have 280 as Packing weight value to 285. So I am using this:

```
data1.loc[(data1['Package category'] == 'X') & (data1['Package'] == 'YYS') & (data1['Moisture'] == 'DRY') 
          & (data1['Length'] == 2000) & (data1['Height'] == 209.0),:].replace({280.0:285})
```

The problem is that I would like this replacement to be shown in my original dataframe "data1". 
But if I use the code above it just shows me as it has done the replacement, but going through the original dataframe data1, the change has not been done.

I have to do this analysis for different groups, and at the end, I would like to have these changes shown effectively on my one original dataframe "data1"
Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: after reading this: [Pandas how can 'replace' work after 'loc'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314971/pandas-how-can-replace-work-after-loc)

I suggest the following edit:
let's call for the whole filtering `con` (just it to be more clear here, you should change it your entire conditions for filtering):

```py
data1.loc[con, :] = data1.loc[con,:].replace({280.0:285})
```

`replace` returns a new dataframe

Comment: Hi, actually I already tried this and it gives me: C:\Users\CentenoS\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4263: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  method=method,

Comment: @PatriciaCenteno it's a warning, not an error. Leaving warning aside for a moment, does it works? (let's start from there and then fix warning)

Comment: It is not making the change in the original dataframe "data1". Because if I try to look again at the same group in which I want the change:            `data1.loc[(data1['Package category'] == 'X') & (data1['Package'] == 'YYS') & (data1['Moisture'] == 'DRY')    & (data1['Length'] == 2000) & (data1['Height'] == 209.0),:] `     The packing values are still 280 and 285, instead of only 285

Comment: @PatriciaCenteno Edited my post. My initial solution is wrong

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked, and since I was analyzing different groups, I just created a different filtering variable (con1, con2..) and all the changes were directly made on my original dataframe "data1". So thank you so much!