# Filling NA values with two types of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I used the following code to clean up a dataset I am working on which has two "types" with different mean values. The code runs without error but the data frame isn't updated.

```
wines = pd.read_csv('winequalityN.csv') #Data import
na_list = wines.isna().sum() 
cols_na = na_list[na_list != 0] #Columns that have NA values
means = wines.groupby('type').mean() #Means values for each category grouped by white type (red or white)

# Filling NA values by mean values for red and white 
for t in ['red','white']:
    for c in cols_na.keys():
        wines.loc[wines.type == t, c].fillna(means.loc[t,c], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas how can 'replace' work after 'loc'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314971/pandas-how-can-replace-work-after-loc). In particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48315104/9769953).

Comment: Almost, it seems that if I just write something like  wines.loc[wines.type == t, c] = 5 the data frame isn't sliced. This is something to do with the fillna I think.

Comment: Thank you, solved with your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay problem solved thanks to a comment left. Use the following for loop instead:

```
      for t in ['red','white']:
          m = wines['type'] == t
              for c in cols_na.keys():
                  wines.loc[m, c] = wines.loc[m, c].fillna(means.loc[t,c])
```

Here the inplace=True comment is uneccessary.

Thanks!