# How to create columns based on combinations of values between 2 sets of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

I have a dataframe with comma separated values that i split out out using pd.concat.

original df:

```
org    country         type
Orange   USA, GBR, AUS   OWF, PMR, KIQ
Red      AUS, RUS, NZL   DOG, MOP, LOF
```

splitting out columns gives me a df, which we'll call df_wide,

```
org        country_1    country_2   country_3   type_1   type_2   type_3
Orange        USA          GBR         AUS         OWF      PMR      KIQ
Watermelon    AUS          RUS         NZL         ODG      MOP      LOF
```

From the above dataframe, i need to get every possible combination of a single country and single type in a long format:

```
org     country    type
Orange  USA        OWF
Orange  USA        PMR
Orange  USA        KIQ
Orange  GBR        OWF
Orange  GBR        PMR
Orange  GBR        KIQ
```

..and so forth

and this is where I'm stuck. I mistakenly thought that i could just transform the dataframe using pd.wide_to_long, but I think the answer my revolves around using itertools. I've searched the forums that relate to this issue, but I still haven't quite figured it out. Looking for any suggestions!  also the commas separated values in the original df columns could be dozens of values and therefore I don’t know how many columns wide my wide df will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution using `itertools.product`. It doesn't require the intermediary dataframe you created.

```
from itertools import chain, product

df = pd.DataFrame({'org': ['Orange', 'Red'],
                   'country': ['USA, GBR, AUS', 'AUS, RUS, NZL'],
                   'type': ['OWF, PMR, KIQ', 'DOG, MOP, LOF']})

split1 = df['country'].str.split(', ')
split2 = df['type'].str.split(', ')

lens = split1.map(len) * split2.map(len)

c_list, t_list = zip(*chain.from_iterable(map(product, split1, split2)))

res = pd.DataFrame({'org': np.repeat(df['org'], lens),
                    'country': c_list,
                    'type': t_list})
```

**Explanation**

The magic happens with this line:

```
c_list, t_list = zip(*chain.from_iterable(map(product, split1, split2)))
```

Working from the inside out:

- Calculate the Cartesian product for each pair of items across `split1` / `split2`.
- Chain them together into a non-nested iterable of results.
- Unpack and zip into countries and types.

**Result**

```
print(res)

      org country type
0  Orange     USA  OWF
0  Orange     USA  PMR
0  Orange     USA  KIQ
0  Orange     GBR  OWF
0  Orange     GBR  PMR
0  Orange     GBR  KIQ
0  Orange     AUS  OWF
0  Orange     AUS  PMR
0  Orange     AUS  KIQ
1     Red     AUS  DOG
1     Red     AUS  MOP
1     Red     AUS  LOF
1     Red     RUS  DOG
1     Red     RUS  MOP
1     Red     RUS  LOF
1     Red     NZL  DOG
1     Red     NZL  MOP
1     Red     NZL  LOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Just borrow jpp 's setting up , using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`

```
df['country'] = df['country'].str.split(', ')
df['type'] = df['type'].str.split(', ')
s=[pd.MultiIndex.from_product(x).tolist() for x in list(zip(df['country'],df['type']))]

df=pd.DataFrame({'org':df.org.repeat(list(map(len,s)))}).reset_index(drop=True)

df[['country','type']]=pd.DataFrame(sum(s,[]))
df
       org country type
0   Orange     USA  OWF
1   Orange     USA  PMR
2   Orange     USA  KIQ
3   Orange     GBR  OWF
4   Orange     GBR  PMR
5   Orange     GBR  KIQ
6   Orange     AUS  OWF
7   Orange     AUS  PMR
8   Orange     AUS  KIQ
9      Red     AUS  DOG
10     Red     AUS  MOP
11     Red     AUS  LOF
12     Red     RUS  DOG
13     Red     RUS  MOP
14     Red     RUS  LOF
15     Red     NZL  DOG
16     Red     NZL  MOP
17     Red     NZL  LOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting by setting up the df:

```
import pandas
records = [
    {
        "org": "Orange",
        "country_1": "USA",
        "country_2": "GBR",
        "country_3": "AUS",
        "type_1": "OWF",
        "type_2": "PMR",
        "type_3": "KIQ"
    },
    {
        "org": "Watermelon",
        "country_1": "AUS",
        "country_2": "RUS",
        "country_3": "NZL",
        "type_1": "ODG",
        "type_2": "MOP",
        "type_3": "LOF"
    }
]

df = pandas.DataFrame(records)
```

First off you can use the `.filter` method of the `pandas.DataFrame` to select out columns through a regex (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808430/how-to-select-columns-from-dataframe-by-regex)):

```
>>> df_countries = df.filter(regex=("country_.*"))
  country_1 country_2 country_3
0       USA       GBR       AUS
1       AUS       RUS       NZL

>>> df_types = df.filter(regex=("type_.*"))
  type_1 type_2 type_3
0    OWF    PMR    KIQ
1    ODG    MOP    LOF
```

Then you can get all unique countries and types as such:

```
>>> countries_all = df_countries.values.flatten()
array(['USA', 'GBR', 'AUS', 'AUS', 'RUS', 'NZL'], dtype=object)
>>> types_all = df_types.values.flatten()
array(['OWF', 'PMR', 'KIQ', 'ODG', 'MOP', 'LOF'], dtype=object)
```

combining them then is a matter of using a cartesian-product from `itertools`:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(*[list(countries_all), list(types_all)])))
      0    1
0   USA  OWF
1   USA  PMR
2   USA  KIQ
3   USA  ODG
4   USA  MOP
5   USA  LOF
6   GBR  OWF
7   GBR  PMR
8   GBR  KIQ
9   GBR  ODG
10  GBR  MOP
11  GBR  LOF
12  AUS  OWF
13  AUS  PMR
14  AUS  KIQ
15  AUS  ODG
16  AUS  MOP
17  AUS  LOF
18  AUS  OWF
19  AUS  PMR
20  AUS  KIQ
21  AUS  ODG
22  AUS  MOP
23  AUS  LOF
24  RUS  OWF
25  RUS  PMR
26  RUS  KIQ
27  RUS  ODG
28  RUS  MOP
29  RUS  LOF
30  NZL  OWF
31  NZL  PMR
32  NZL  KIQ
33  NZL  ODG
34  NZL  MOP
35  NZL  LOF
```

Now I understand you might wanna do this per `org` in which case I'd subset the dataframe prior to doing the filter:

```
orgs = pandas.unique(df["org"])
for org in orgs:
    df_org = df[df["org"] == org]
    df_countries = df_org.filter(regex=("country_.*"))
    df_types = df_org.filter(regex=("type_.*"))
    # do rest of the process here and concatenate in the end through `pandas.concat`
```

Hope this helps