# How to set effective start and end condition for column selection with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have to select columns that start with a given letter (variable is called `sLetter`) and after that letter has to be a figure. If sLetter would be `v` than `v1, v399` and so on. `ve1` would be invalid as well as `v100e`.

I started to play around with `regular expressions` to solve the problem using

```
df.filter(regex=(sLetter + ".[1-9]"))
```

I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808430/how-to-select-columns-from-dataframe-by-regex) and in the answers I found an analysis about the speed of this approach compared with using a `lambda expression` and this shows that the latter is much faster. Unfortunately I cannot come up with a lamdba expression that solves my problem. I can accomplish the selection of `sLetter` with

```
df.columns.map(lambda x: x.startswith(sLetter))
```

but here it ends. Anyone who can help me out creating a faster solution than the one I already have?

Comment: How import is it for you that you can use the `sLetter` variable instead of hardcoding the `v` into the regex?

Comment: Crucial since the user can choose frome a range of letters what columns he wants to manipulate via an interface. So he can choose 'v' or 't' aso.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `regex` and specify that the column has to start with `^sLetter` and that the amount of numbers has to be three and that it has to end with those numbers `$`.

```
# Make example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'v874':[1,2,3],
                   'v100e':[4,5,6],
                   've1':[7,8,9],
                   'v399':[10,11,12]})
df
   v874  v100e  ve1  v399
0     1      4    7    10
1     2      5    8    11
2     3      6    9    12
```

---

```
sLetter = 'v'

df.filter(regex= '^' + sLetter + r'[0-9]{3}$')

   v874  v399
0     1    10
1     2    11
2     3    12
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of `str` + `contains` method as well. To filter, you can use:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('^v+[0-9]')]
```

You could use `map` like this (negate the expression for correct results):

```
import re
df.loc[:, df.columns.map(lambda x: not re.match('^(?!v+[0-9])', x))]
```

Comment: Would this suffice for the case that it has to have three numbers followed by the `sLetter`?