# Change DataTypes of Pandas Columns by selecting columns by regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with a lot of columns looking like p_d_d_c0, p_d_d_c1, ... p_d_d_g1, p_d_d_g2, ....

```
  df = 
        a     b     c      p_d_d_c0     p_d_d_c1    p_d_d_c2 ... p_d_d_g0  p_d_d_g1 ...
```

All these columns, which confirm to the regex need to be selected and their datatypes need to be changed from object to float. In particular, columns look like p_d_d_c* and p_d_d_g* are they are all `object` types and I would like to change them to `float` types. Is there a way to select columns in bulk by using regular expression and change them to float types?

I tried the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808430/how-to-select-columns-from-dataframe-by-regex), but it takes a lot of time and memory as I have hundreds of these columns.

```
    df[df.filter(regex=("p_d_d_.*"))
```

I also tried:

```
    df.select(lambda col: col.startswith('p_d_d_g'), axis=1)
```

But, it gives an error:

```
    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'select'
```

My Pandas version is `1.0.1`

So, how to select columns in bulk and change their data types using regex?

Comment: can you explain briefly what you are trying to do? what are your rules for converting characters into float values?

Comment: are you trying to select columns which conform to a certain regex? or are you trying to convert series containing object data (characters) to floats?

Comment: I am trying to select columns which conform to a certain regex and change all these selected columns from `object` type to `float` type

Comment: got it. see my solution below,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"co1":[1,2,3,4], "co22":[4,3,2,1], "co3":[2,3,2,4], "abc":[5,4,3,2]})

# select all columns which have co in it
floatcols = [col for col in df.columns if "co" in col]

for floatcol in floatcols:
    df[floatcol] = df[floatcol].astype(float)
```

Comment: Is there a way to speed up this? In particular line with `astype`?

Answer (score 3):

From the same link, and with some `astype` magic.

```py
column_vals = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.startswith("p_d_d_"))
train_temp = df.loc(axis=1)[column_vals]
train_temp = train_temp.astype(float)
```

---

EDIT:

To modify the original dataframe, do something like this:

```py
column_vals = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith("p_d_d_")]
df[column_vals] = df[column_vals].astype(float)
```

Comment: Hi @apurvmishra99, won't it change the original dataframe. I added train_temp by mistake. There is only one dataframe `df`